# Is something like AfterSelectionChanged event exist for ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview, multi-select

I have a list of items in ListView and I need something like AfterSelectionChanged event. Now I am subscribed to ItemSelectionChanged but it is triggered N times if I press Ctrl+A in list with N items. But I need to be notified only one time after all items would be selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: WinForms((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own by delaying a method call until all the ItemSelectionChanged events stopped firing.  Which is very cleanly done by Control.BeginInvoke().  Make it look similar to this:

```
    List<int> afterSelect = new List<int>();

    private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {            
        if (afterSelect.Count == 0) this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listView1_AfterSelectionChanged()));
        afterSelect.Add(e.ItemIndex);
    }

    private void listView1_AfterSelectionChanged() {
        // Use afterSelect
        //..
        afterSelect.Clear();
    }
```

You can use a bool flag instead of the List<> if you don't need to keep track of which items changed.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain why does it work? I mean the sequence of events handling and this async invocation. May be you can share a link to any article on this subject?

Comment: @SKINDER Please beware that this works only if no messages are processed by the UI thread between item selections. If you, for example, try to select all items manually (e.g. by clicking on them while holding CTRL, or by using the left-click-hold "lasso"), `listView1_AfterSelectionChanged` would execute before you have selected all the items.

Comment: I don't know of any articles.  It is the exact same approach as using PostMessage in native UI programming.  Add a message to the message queue, find it back once the UI thread goes idle again.  It is also used in Winforms itself, the Form.Shown event is generated this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == listView1.Items.Count) {
        // All items selected.
    }
}
```